# Jquery Cropping image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use this http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/examples.html Jquery Cropping  example to get the dimension from jquery and send it to my java, so the java file does the cropping for me or i just do it here on the client side, but it doesnt work for me here is a code that i wrote http://jsfiddle.net/UydpR/ to be honest i have no idea what I am doing or how I am suppose to write this, I thought if I just say  it will give me the rest of the options...any help or example of the code would be appriciated... I did follow their documentation but I am pretty new at this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fiddle setup isn't correct. you use mootools instead of jQuery. First of all you have to change this. Also you code had a lot of problems, so you have to change it.

You can check out a Version with cropping an Image in this Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UydpR/2/

If you add a Form with hidden fields and a php file like this code below you can submit the selection coordinates. I havent tried this yet but the developer of the script makes this example.

Add a form with hidden fields (with the names listed below) to your HTML Code.

Add this to the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#ladybug').imgAreaSelect({
    onSelectEnd: function (img, selection) {
        $('input[name="x1"]').val(selection.x1);
        $('input[name="y1"]').val(selection.y1);
        $('input[name="x2"]').val(selection.x2);
        $('input[name="y2"]').val(selection.y2);            
    }
});
```

});

Be sure that you have make a php file and. Submit the form data to your PHP file and do what you like with it.

**Here you can find the tutorial: http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/examples-callback.html#submitting-selection-coordinates-demo**

Answer (score 1):

Remove the below line from  script :

```
onSelectEnd: someFunction
```

Sample working code for you :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/imgareaselect-default.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/imgareaselect-animated.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/imgareaselect-deprecated.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.imgareaselect.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div>

<img id="imgareaselect-selection" width="400" src="http://chrisharrison.net/projects/colorflower/Flower2medium.jpg" alt="My image" name="photo" />

</div>

<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; z-index: 2; ">
<div style="position: absolute; font-size: 0px; " class="imgareaselect-selection"></div>
<div style="position: absolute; font-size: 0px; " class="imgareaselect-border1"></div>
<div style="position: absolute; font-size: 0px; " class="imgareaselect-border2"></div>
<div style="position: absolute; font-size: 0px; " class="imgareaselect-border3"></div>
<div style="position: absolute; font-size: 0px; " class="imgareaselect-border4"></div>
<div class="imgareaselect-handle" style="position: absolute; font-size: 0px; z-index: 1; width: 5px; height: 5px; "></div>
<div class="imgareaselect-handle" style="position: absolute; font-size: 0px; z-index: 1; width: 5px; height: 5px; "></div>
<div class="imgareaselect-handle" style="position: absolute; font-size: 0px; z-index: 1; width: 5px; height: 5px; "></div>
<div class="imgareaselect-handle" style="position: absolute; font-size: 0px; z-index: 1; width: 5px; height: 5px; "></div>
<div class="imgareaselect-handle" style="position: absolute; font-size: 0px; z-index: 1; width: 5px; height: 5px; "></div>
<div class="imgareaselect-handle" style="position: absolute; font-size: 0px; z-index: 1; width: 5px; height: 5px; "></div>
<div class="imgareaselect-handle" style="position: absolute; font-size: 0px; z-index: 1; width: 5px; height: 5px; "></div>
<div class="imgareaselect-handle" style="position: absolute; font-size: 0px; z-index: 1; width: 5px; height: 5px; "></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>​
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img').imgAreaSelect({
        handles: true,

    });
    $('img').imgAreaSelect({
    onSelectEnd: function (img, selection) {
        alert('width: ' + selection.width + '; height: ' + selection.height);
    }
});
$('img').imgAreaSelect({
    keys: { arrows: 15, ctrl: 5, shift: 'resize' }
});
});
</script>
<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-3683332-2");
pageTracker._initData();
pageTracker._trackPageview();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question.  Do you want the width in pixels?

In that case, it is VERY easy:
    var w = $('tag').width();
    var h = $('tag').height();

Now you can get clever with how you define these, say....

```
var w = $('tag').width() / $(window).width(); //is the percentage of the width of the browser that the picture has.
```

Then it is fairly straight forward to w*.5, will reduce by 2 the width of the browser, etc.

Please elaborate if you need more.

Comment: From there you could eyeball the width in percentages.  So if you wanted to crop, say 1/8 from the sides, you could w*.75.